# pubsub to bigquery without dataflow using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub, pypubsub

I am looking to execute a code to read data from pub sub and store into a Big Table using python code.The requirement is not to use data flow options.

Could you please let me know for any template or sample code to achieve the same.

Thanks in Advance!.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Google Cloud Functions, it has PubSub as a trigger:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub

Your cloud function will receive the pubsub event and can then inject it into bigquery